# How can the shape for a node be different from triangle, circle, square at Python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

There is Python code that constructs a simple graph with nodes of different shapes: triangle, circle, square.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node("circle", shape="o")
G.add_node("square", shape="s")
G.add_node("triangle", shape="^")

G.add_edge("circle", "square")
G.add_edge("square", "triangle")
G.add_edge("triangle", "circle")

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_shape="o", nodelist=["circle"], node_color="skyblue", node_size=2000)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_shape="s", nodelist=["square"], node_color="lightgreen", node_size=2000)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_shape="^", nodelist=["triangle"], node_color="salmon", node_size=2000)

plt.show()
```

How can shape for a node be different, for example, an ellipse or a trapezoid?